# How to perform multiple joins in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have a stored procedure that I'm converting to LINQ, but I'm a little stuck. Here's the SQL:

```
    select 
      @name                             = tp.Name
,     @Entity                           = tc.Entity
,     @Name                             = tc.Name
,     @ID                               =  tpt.ID
,     @Code                             =  tptr.Code  

    from tbltprop tp 

    Left join tblcol tc                                on ( tc.id = tp.ID )
    Left join tblPropday  tpt               on ( tpt.Id = tp.Id )
    Left join tblProperResult tptr   on (tptr.ID = tpt.Id )

    where tp.id               = @chsarpID1 //input ID i get in c#
    and     tpt.Id = @chsarpID2
```

I understand how to do a single join, but I'm having some trouble making a multiple join work. How would one go about this?

Comment: Did you have a specific problem with this conversion that we could help you with? Or did you just want us to write your code for you...

Comment: Please re write the same code in C#, i don't no syntax :(, i'm dumb in SQL query syntax, sorry and thanks for ur reply

Comment: Unfortunately StackOverflow is a Q&A site, we tend to not write code for people. I'd suggest you read and learn about LINQ and SQL and, of course, come back if you get stuck on any *specific* bits. Good luck!

Comment: na, i know linq sql.. but my doubt is how to write the multiple joins in C#, single join somehow i learnt but multiple join i don no :(

Comment: refer this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696616/convert-sql-query-to-linq-contains-left-joins?rq=1

Comment: You may want to edit the question to make your intent more clear then. As it stands it reads like "write code please" rather than "I know I can do a single join like this, but how do I perform more than one".

Comment: Done alexander, thanks for ur reply

Comment: I've not played with left joins much but I'm confused as to how more than one can be any different from one. Any join will leave you with an enumerable that can then be used in another left join easily enough...

Comment: Why don't you show your class model? There's a lot we have to make up for you, like which navigation properties there are. Using nav properties makes this so much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you.......

```
var values= from tp in tbltprop
            join tb in tblcol ON tp.id equals tb.id into gj
            from gjd in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join tpt in tblPropday ON tp.id equals tpt.id into gk
            from gkd in gk.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join tptr in tblProperResult ON tp.id equals tptr.id into gl
            from gld in gl.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where tp.id == @charpID1 && gkd.Id == @CharpID2
            select new 
                   { 
                       TpName = tp.Name, 
                       Entity = gjd.Entity, 
                       TPTName = gjd.Name, 
                       ID = gkd.ID, 
                       Code = gld.Code
                   };
```

Comment: You're not going to be able to have 2 properties both called `Name` in the `select` part.

Comment: Gopesh, thanks for your reply, i'm getting error if i use int in where clause i.e can't implicitly convert int to bool ?.

Comment: @LLL I have edited the answer, typo mistake, there will be two equal to sign, previously it was one...

Comment: Thanks Gopesh, Thanks lot, i m implementing this, thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Gopesh, i m not getting how to use the inner selected var i.e values.TpName, values.Entity. its not coming, is it something extra we need to do for accessing them?

Comment: can you please add .ToList() at the end after keeping the whole query in a bracket and try?

Comment: Na, its not showing if i hit '.', i tried to list. are there any alternatives?

Comment: it should show, can you please tell me whats the data type of **values** you are getting?

Comment: I have made values as var. but i'm seeling the inner variables as anonymous types. but if i hit "." its not showing :(

Comment: i got it, thanks lot i need to access like values[0]. so it works in this way

Comment: its good it worked, but . should work..i dont know why its not working

Comment: without to list will it work?. just for knowledge sake i'm asking u