# Writing the LINQ equaivalent of a SQL join

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

This is the SQL query I have written:

```
select * from Addresses a 
join ProviderAddresses pa on a.address_k =  pa.address_k
where pa.provider_k = 'ABC123'
and pa.active = 1
and a.active = 1
and pa.addresstype_rtk = 'HOME'
```

And this is the LINQ query I wrote for it:

```
public IQueryable<Addresses> GetAddressesesForProvider(string provider_k, string addresstype_rtk)
{
    var query = from a in this.Context.Addresses
        join pa in this.Context.ProviderAddresses on a.Address_K equals pa.Address_K
        where pa.AddressType_RTK == addresstype_rtk
                                   && pa.Active == true
                                   && a.Active == true
        select a;

    return query;
}
```

But it is wrong. The LINQ one return thousands of records and the SQL one returns only one record.

It is `IQueryable` because later I need to go through its results with a for-each loop.
In the SQL I am passing hard coded values for testing but in my code for me LINQ method I also pass the same hard coded values so that is not the issue.

Comment: A good start would be to review this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696616/convert-sql-query-to-linq-contains-left-joins?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you may have just missed adding the `provider_k` condition to the `where`;

```
public IQueryable<Addresses> GetAddressesesForProvider(string provider_k, string addresstype_rtk)
{
    var query = from a in this.Context.Addresses
        join pa in this.Context.ProviderAddresses on a.Address_K equals pa.Address_K
        where pa.Provider_K == provider_k &&
              pa.AddressType_RTK == addresstype_rtk &&
              pa.Active == true &&
              a.Active == true
        select a;

    return query;
}
```